Avoid unescaped/sanitized content in output - Sonarqube
I'm struggling to fix this Sonarqube issue related to avoid unescaped/sanitized content in output, this is original code:
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<div aura:id="collapsible" class="slds-p-horizontal_small slds-section slds-is-open">
        <iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="{!'/apex/VF_RetailDetails?Id=' + v.recordId }" scrolling="auto" frameBorder="0"/>
    </div>

</aura:component>
Issue is with v.recordId attribute, recommendation is to use JSENCODE() function but when I try to use it I got this error --> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION. Failed to save RetailDetails.cmp: No function found for key: JSENCODE: Source
I have also tried with HTMLENCODE() but no luck also.
I can't get to fix this issue if anyone could help please. Thanks in advance.

If you implements="force:hasRecordId" - don't explicitly list the attribute in the code, the component will work as if it was injected in there already.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation

Note If your component implements force:hasRecordId, you don’t need to
add a recordId attribute to the component yourself. If you do add it,
don’t change the access level or type of the attribute or the
component will cause a runtime error.

You could try to silence the scanner by constructing the url in JS (controller or helper), not in html. It's also how you'd have to do it in LWC, put more logic in JS, can't craft expressions like that.
Aura doesn't have JSENCODE functions from Visualforce/formulas syntax. You can do "only" these in the component: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm Everything else has to be in proper JS.
When all else fails... You could just suppress the SQ warning for this line and move on. You know a valid ID will be passed, put a comment about false positive and move on. Looks like more people have similar problems and really SQ should be updated... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383538/unescaped-attribute-value-xss-how-to-sanitized-event-handlers-in-lightning-aur

Thanks a lot for your help, finally we have suppressed this warning as this seems to be a false positive from SQ.
